# Angular 13 package/library throws error "moment is not a function" when imported into a Angular 13 project

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-library, ng-packagr

Im upgrading a private angular library/package (my-lib) so i can migrate all other projects, but when imported into a project one of the services uses moment and throws an error:
"ERROR TypeError: moment is not a function"

The library works in dev mode and the build and publish are ok and even when imported into a project all components and resources load fine and no errors are displayed, dependencies are download but seeams that some of the 3rd party dependencies are not known by "my-lib" after imported.

Even in the project i can import moment and use it but "my-lib" in node_modules dont see that package.

some of the files in "my-lib"

**service.ts**

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment';

const moment = moment_;
...

moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')  ----> line that throws the error
```

already tried

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and the "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" flag in tsconfig

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "moment": "~2.29.1",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "ng-packagr": "~13.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

**tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "cypress",
      "cypress-xpath",
      "cypress-wait-until"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial",
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "cypress",
      "cypress-xpath",
      "cypress-wait-until"
    ]
  }
}
```

**ng-package.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "./src/my-lib/public_api.ts",
    "cssUrl": "inline"
  },
  "allowedNonPeerDependencies": ["."]
}
```

this is a update from angular 9 to 13 and probably im missing something but cannot find examples or documentation that explains the change in behavior.

ps: The "require" function has the same behavior

```
const a = require('assets/test.png');   --> throws error require is not a function when my-lib is imported into a project and tries to run the this line
```

If you need more details or have some suggestions i will apreciate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this issue trying to run moment in stackblitz. Setting `"esModuleInterop":true` in `compilerOptions` **and** using the `import moment from 'moment'` syntax fixed it for me. Let me know if that works.

Enabling `esmoduleInterop` also enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

More info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

Comment: https://imgur.com/gMY1pXq

error when build the library with the `import moment from 'moment'` and `"esModuleInterop":true` in compilerOptions

Comment: Make sure you don't have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set to false. Maybe just add it and set it to true for good measure.

Comment: i did. i think my lib project is dirty i will try to start from scratch and see if it works.
thanks for the help.

Comment: i did a new library project and with the options you said it works now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have enough rep at the moment to write a comment I wanted to emphasize what Chris Hamilton said in the comments which helped me solve the problem:

> Make sure you don't have allowSyntheticDefaultImports set to false. **Maybe just add it and set it to true for good measure**.

I had the same issues when upgrading a library to Angular 13.
Already fixed up the imports (`import moment from 'moment'`), added the `"esModuleInterop":true` to compilerOptions of the base projects main.ts but it didnt' work.
I additionally had to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` for it to work although it had not been previously set to false. Apparently in some cases it needs to be there in addition to `"esModuleInterop":true`.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to comment either due to rep, but Chris's answer, saved us some headaches (we upgraded from Angular 11 --> 14)...
One other thing for us we had to do and noticed, was we use ng-packagr for our components as they are used by another app as a dependency...in that case, we had to pass a config (that didn't use full ivy compilation mode) via ng-packagr -c  that set allowSyntheticDefaultImports to true, as esModuleInterop didn't seem to also set this property for ng-packagr only.